# HERE Toll cost calculation information missing

Tags: here-api

I am trying to implement a route calculator with the HERE API. I should show the toll costs of the given route for the user. However, I have some questions, I could not find any answer in the documentation for:

1. Are the given toll costs net value, i.e. is VAT included or not? Based on my test requests, it looks like there are some countries where VAT is included, and it is excluded in others. Are there any arguments in the result from HERE providing information on this?
2. One can specify the currency in which the costs are calculated, but I could not find any information on the exchange rates applied. I would like to show this also for the user. Is it possible to get this in the result, too? Or maybe is the source of this data public?
3. As the toll costs and the toll roads may change over time, I would like to also show the time of data for the user. Is there any argument for this given back by HERE in the result?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this API (or if the question is answerable in the current state), but you should show some of your existing code for context.

Comment: @user202729 Sorry, but I do not really understand, what kind of code should I include. I think these are questions about the concepts of the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the HERE Fleet Telematics API.

1. VAT is expected to always be included. No, there is no such argument in the API.
2. No, you cannot get this information in the results. The only trick I can suggest, is to make 2 consecutive calls to the API, one using the first currency and another one using the second currency, and therefore derive from these results the applied exchange rate.
3. There's no such argument. You should assume that HERE's toll cost data is always fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Toll cost calculation is provided via Here Fleet Telematics API.

1. Total toll cost includes the VAT
   And as per the documentation the below details can be retrieved.

In addition, toll cost detail can be requested on different levels, using the "rollups" parameter:

a. total summary only
b. cost per road link
c. cost per country
d. cost per toll system

2. Exchange rates are not provided rather currency can be provided.
3. There is  no history of route calculation provided , all the data that are provided are latest.